# Gold, Silver, Bronze color swatches

Tags: inkscape, metallic

I am working on an app that displays various colors for kids to choose from.  So, we'll have a red, a blue, a yellow, etc.  These are not real objects, just a small image (like the one attached) that represents a color.[image]

They are all 600x600px squares.

I have been asked to include one for Silver, one for Gold, and one for Bronze (if possible), but to make them look more "realistic" (which I take to mean they need something besides plain RGB colors).

What I'm looking for is an approach to creating "realistic" swatches for these metallic colors.  I realize this is likely a very broad category, and not being fluent with graphic design, I wonder if anyone can make suggestions to approaches.  I will be fumbling through this with Inkscape.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: All I see is blue!!!!! :) Possibly helpful: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5246/3270 Are gradients available or do they have to be flat colors? If flat, what colors would you choose yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gradients for this. Below is a screenshot, but illustrator comes with quite a few metallic swatches by default.

[image: Metallic Gradients]

Comment: The key here is that 'silver, gold, and bronze' aren't really colors. They are materials--more specifically, surfaces that are (typically) shiny and reflective. Silver = shiny gray. Gold = shiny yellow. Bronze = shiny brown. What these gradients have is a white light highlight and is what makes them look shiny.

Comment: Agree with @DA01 - these are _surfaces_ of objects, not colours as such. And btw -the question was for inkscape, not photoshop or illustrator.

Comment: Thanks to both for your replies. This answer did give me an approach.

Comment: @Eddie A. you mention Illustrator but this question ask for Inkscape program so I think it isn't going to be so helpful.

Comment: @PhoneixS I would disagree as this is a method that can be used with any program that has color gradient editor.

Comment: But how can the user use the Illustrator gradients? And if he doesn't have it? I'm ok with the use of gradients of your answer (it's what must be used to archive metallic appearance), my complain was about the illustrator by itself because you don't add any information of this gradients for a user of Inkscape. I don't know if I explain correctly why I want to say.

Answer (score 5):

If you're working with flat color and not textures or gradients, this is not going to be perfect, as others have noted. However, you can suggest these metallic tones with the right color. If you go that route, the only thing that will make your intent clear is to label them.

**Gold** is a muted yellow, eg [#d5a500](http://0to255.com/d5a500).

**Bronze** is a muted yellow orange, eg [#a17419](http://0to255.com/a17419).

**Silver** is light grey, eg [#b7b7b7](http://0to255.com/b7b7b7).