# How is this gold 3D effect created?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, 3d

So, we've probably all seen the images that showcase the font.

I came across one (see attached) and I've been looking to create this effect for a long time but didn't find anything.

[image: The effect in "Bauru"]

Here's the font [Bauru](https://www.behance.net/gallery/23499145/Bauru-Free-Font)

Can anyone tell me how this effect is created in Photoshop or what this is called so I can look up some tutorials?

Edit:

The perspective and focus is fine, but how's the 3D edges created and how's that lighting on the edges is done, like on the rounded areas of B?

Comment: Not everything a designer does "must" automatically be "a Photoshop Effect". (In fact, it's quite insulting to assume all a designer does is 'type text, apply Effect X, send to client'.)

Comment: @Jongware Are you saying this is actual hardware? I'm not saying this is some magical predefined effect built into the photoshop. This is excellent work and I wanna learn to create it. No disrespect to the artist, that's for sure

Comment: What have you tried and what do you mean exactly by "effect"? The gold letters, the engraving, or the perspective?

Comment: The perspective and focus is fine, but how's the 3D edges created and how's that lighting on the edges is done, like on the rounded areas of B?

Comment: There are a squadrillion tutorials on metallic 3D text effects out there. It would be good if you showed us what you have tried, and where you get stuck.

Comment: Does it look like 3D? Dont you think it could be done in a 3D program? The point here is not just the rounded areas, but the ilumination and material, and that must be done in a 3D program with a photorealistic render egine. Try blender.org with the cycles render engine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how to create the focus effect and perspective, why not have a look at the 3D features of Photoshop.

It's probably the easiest way to have that reflection you want on your letters and you can combine what you'll create in 3D with other effects and filter.

**Simply use that font you found, type your text, and try "New 3D extrusion from selected layer" in the 3D menu.**

[image: 3D menu create a 3D text]

Then play around with the lights, add a few, change their colors, etc. For this cheap example, I added 2 lights only and the text I started with was flat and gray.

The example below is a 5 minutes test with no rendering and no blending effect or anything applied; if you spend some time discovering the 3D of Photoshop and playing around with it and what you already know (and rendering it), you'll get your gold effect and more shine!

[image: gold letters]

**Here's a link with a pretty nice gold effect!**

[How do I create realistic looking gold in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-do-i-create-realistic-looking-gold-in-photoshop)